# ViewPager or ViewFlipper or something else for unlimited set of data?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewflipper

My source of data can me give unlimited set of data (it's like days in calendar). I have to show each item separately on screen (one item at a time). For each item I have to make query into my data source. I don't know which approach will be better ViewPager (how handle in adapter unlimited count?) or ViewFlipper? Or maybe there is a third solution (the best one).

Can you put some links to examples. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only showing 1 item at a time, use ViewPager

If you want to show multiple items on the same page, use RecyclerView.

For calendar, it seems more close to ViewPager

Comment: thanks. In case viewPager, how to handle in adapter unlimited count of data?

Comment: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.hk/2014/01/hack-trick-endless-viewpager-example-in.html just found this on google

Comment: Actually you should try it first and if some problem you can't overcome in the process, ask here, this is how it works in stackoverflow